# MVC 4 Action Redirect attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, action

I have a link coming into our MVC 4 site which I can't alter.

http://somesite.com/MyController/ugly_name

Is there a way to put an attribute over an Action to say "send ugly_name here"

```
[Action???("ugly_name")]
public ActionResult NiceName(){}
```

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just return a redirecttoaction result from the controller action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use AttributeRouting. below is an example:

Install the AttributeRouting from package manager:

```
PM> Install-Package AttributeRouting
```

**Controller**

```
[RoutePrefix("/MyController")]
[RoutePrefix("/Home")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{

   [GET("ugly_name")]
   public ActionResult NiceName() { /* ... */ }
}
```